# Spark/pyspark on same version but "py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction does not exist"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a properly sync'ed `pyspark` client / `spark` installation: both versions are 3.3.1 [ shown below].  The full exception message is:

> py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction([class [B, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2]) does not exist

This has been identified in [another SOF post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72873963/py4jexception-constructor-org-apache-spark-sql-sparksessionclass-org-apache-s) as most likely due to versioning mismatch between the `pyspark` invoker/caller and the `spark` backend. I agree that would seem the likely cause: but then I have verified carefully that both sides of the equation are equal:

`pyspark` and `spark` are same versions:

```
Python 3.10.13 (main, Aug 24 2023, 22:48:59) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)]

In [1]: import pyspark

In [2]: print(f"PySpark version: {pyspark.__version__}")
PySpark version: 3.3.1
```

`Spark` was installed by downloading the version 3.3.1 .tgz directly from the `apache` site and unzip/tar-ring. The `SPARK_HOME` was pointed to that directory and the `$SPARK_HOME/bin` added to the path.

```
$spark-shell --version

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.1
      /_/
```

Inside the python script the version has been verified as well:

> pyspark version: 3.3.1

But the script blows up with a pyspark / spark error

> An error occurred while calling [None.org](http://None.org).apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction

> py4j.Py4JException: Constructor org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonFunction([class [B, class java.util.HashMap, class java.util.ArrayList, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String, class java.util.ArrayList, class org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorV2]) does not exist
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getConstructor(ReflectionEngine.java:180)

So .. what else might be going on here? Is there some way I'm not seeing in which the versions of spark/pyspark might be out of sync?

Comment: Can you add a bit more information about your setup? How did you install Spark? And since you're using notebooks, how did you make the link between your notebook and Spark? Are you running the notebook inside of a virtual environment?

Comment: @Koedlt  I corrected from `notebook` to `script`  . It is the exported python code from an earlier notebook.  I'll add about how spark was installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pycharm` situation. Looks like I had not restarted it after twiddling between versions of `spark`. It remembered an earlier version of the default (for `homebrew`) of `3.5.0`